# Repositioning stat_summary count numbers in ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
df2<-data.frame(id=c("a","f","f","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","",""),
                var=c(12,20,15,18,10,30,5,8,5,5,3,5))

give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = mean(x), label = length(x)))
}
ggplot(data=subset(df2, id != ""), aes(x = reorder(id, -var), y = var)) +
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text", 
               position = position_jitter(height=1, width = 0))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size=11, vjust = -.005))+
  ggtitle("Title")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("value")
```

I have the above plot, however I would like to position the counts above the median line in the boxplot so they are more visible. Using position_jitter in this way does not always prevent the count number from overlapping with the median bar. Any suggestions?
*edited to provide df2

Comment: Please provide data also for the problem

Comment: Have you tried `position_nudge` instead of `position_jitter`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the adjustment in the returned `y =` value. For example, have it return the median + 0.1. You would have to adjust the 0.1 manually for your data.

```
give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = median(x) + 0.1, label = length(x)))
}

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.data = give.n, geom = "text")
```

Or if you want it to be exactly centered between the median and the upper hinge, you could compute that position like this:

```
give.n <- function(x){
  return(c(y = mean(fivenum(x)[3:4]), label = length(x)))
}
```

[image]